# Java replace with regex

Tags: java

Say I have a string "The shawshank's redemption.". How can I replace every character that is not whitespace with underscore...each underscore representing a word would be separated by one white space while double whitespace would exist to show separate words...

Expected input:

```
"The shawshank's redemption."
```

Expected output:

```
"- - -  - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - -"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: What have you tried? And what is a "double whitespace"?

Comment: Just to be sure we understood you correctly include example of input and expected output. Also include your attempts so we would know what problems you are facing specifically while writing your own solution.

Comment: hats off for reference to the best movie ever made.

Comment: Use [edit] option to improve/clarify your question.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I understand what OP means. The Shawshank's Redemption would turn into "_ _ _  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _"

Comment: @Sweeper That could be in what Graipher posted, but comments can't print two consecutive whitespaces, it will be limited to one, even in `code  
 section  (I  used  two     and      more       spaces        here)`

Comment: @Pshemo oh I see! Sorry Graipher!

Comment: yh....i edited the post.....@ElliottFrisch and @Sweeper

Comment: @ElliottFrisch.....i tried using regex to replace all letters in the string using replace all and a for loop...but whiteSpace still returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as:

```
"The Shawshank's Redemption".replaceAll("\\S", " _");
```

We replace all non white-space characters `\S` with an underscore followed by a space. This would automatically make what is a space originally, 2 spaces. Note that a trailing space will be produced.

Comment: wooow...thanks a lot...this works perfectly.....@Sweeper

Comment: yes it works perfectly @Sweeper